# Como reproduzir algo semelhante ao CSS no Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria de fazer um programa com a mesma aparência/estilo que o site, porém no Windows Form não funciona CSS por ser uma tecnologia Web. Então como eu poderia fazer algo parecido?

Comment: É possível, utilizando aplicação híbrida, dá uma lida neste artigo, está em inglês, mas ele mostra como fazer utilizando Electron. http://mylifeforthecode.com/fulfilling-a-mvvm-dream-binding-a-html-view-to-a-csharp-dotnet-viewmodel-with-electron-and-edge-js/

Comment: Lembrando que o Spotify, Slack, entre outros foram feitos com Electron ou algo similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, CSS não é questão de tecnologia Web, é se o renderizador suporta, e no caso não é algo implementado, existem softwares desktop que dão algum suporte semelhante, como o Qt para que usa o QSS, um CSS do Qt, mas isso é outra história.

O importante é entender que cada motor de renderização usa seu proprio "motor css", em navegadores e clientes de e-mail, mas o Windows Forms não tem isto, voltando a falar do que importa, no entanto você pode se interessar pelo *WPF* (Windows Presentation Foundation)

Então algo como no CSS:

```
div {
   font-familty: "Comic Sans MS";
   font-size: 14px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

O template no XAML afetaria todos `TextBlock`s:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
</Style>
```

Fonte para leitura:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styles-and-templates
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating

---

### No entanto XamlCSS

No entanto encontrei este projeto https://github.com/warappa/XamlCSS

- Como começar: https://github.com/warappa/XamlCSS/wiki/Getting-started

Um exemplo para aplicar seria, no `App.xaml.cs` (por exemplo) adicionaria isto:

```
public App()
{
    XamlCSS.XamarinForms.Css.Initialize(this);
    ...
}
```

E no App ficaria mais ou menos isto `App.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:css="clr-namespace:XamlCSS;assembly=XamlCSS"
             x:Class="App.App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <css:StyleSheet x:Key="inlineStyle">
        <css:StyleSheet.Content>
          .important
          {
              BackgroundColor: Red;
              FontSize: 25;
              WidthRequest: 200;
          }
          Label
          {
              TextColor: Red;
              FontSize: 25;
          }
          Button
          {
              TextColor: Blue;
              BackgroundColor: Black;
          }
        </css:StyleSheet.Content>
      </css:StyleSheet>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

### Plataformas suportadas

- XamarinForms

  - NuGet: [`XamlCSS.XamarinForms`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlCSS.XamarinForms)
- WPF

  - NuGet: [`XamlCSS.WPF`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlCSS.WPF)
- Universal Windows Platform

  - NuGet: [`XamlCSS.UWP`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlCSS.UWP)

### Algumas funcionalidades

- Seletores CSS
- Multiplos StyleSheets
- Seletores aninhados (semelhante ao Sass)
- Variaveis no Css
- Importar estilo de outros arquivos CSS
- Mixins

Answer (score 0):

O CSS é especificamente para HTML e não é possível aplicar no Windows Form.
É possível fazer algo similar usando XML.
Verifique esse link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14814/StylesSheetManager-A-CSS-like-component-for-WinFor

Você pode fazer o download do projeto e verificar o exemplo para aplicar no seu código.

Comment: Não é especificamente para HTML, SVG também suporta CSS, mas depende muito do motor de renderização do browser.