# Como posso usar estilos CSS no windows forms c#

Tags: c#, css, winforms

Tenho muitas dificuldades em fazer a parte gráfica dos programas, alguém que possa me ajudar com algum exemplo simples, não precisa ser muito complexo, pois isto é um trabalho de final de curso.

Comment: Quem sabe possa te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262092/como-reproduzir-algo-semelhante-ao-css-no-windows-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar o CSS no Windows Forms pois ele não é compatível, para criar estilos visuais agradáveis, utilize WPF, com ele você tem recursos similares a CSS, pois você pode definir padrões de estilo e aplicá-los em diferentes componentes, para mais informações, segue o link de suporte do WPF: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/wpf/